# send different id to bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have problem with bootstrap modal.

i have number of buttons that call to the same modal. each one send different id to the modal file. the problem is that the modal doesn't get the different id. it only get the first one all the time.

example with JQUERY in the modal: http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/tempFile.php example without JQUERY in the modal: http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/tempFile2.php

if i remove the JQUERY call from the modal than the modal get different id, but other script doesn't work anymore (the upload images script)

main file:

```
<li><a href="modalFile.php?id=1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Send value "1" to modal</a></li>
<li><a href="modalFile.php?id=2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Send value "2" to modal</a></li>
<li><a href="modalFile.php?id=3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Send value "3" to modal</a></li>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title for modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    // clear model content
    $('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
</script>
```

modal file:

```
<div class="modal-body">    
    <form id="modal-form" action="index.php?id=1"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Images</label>
                            <input id="input-8" name="file[]" multiple type="file" class="file-loading*">
                        </div>


                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success submit">Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
                            <div class="form-msg"></div>
                        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/fileinput-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/files_upload/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/files_upload/themes/explorer/theme.js"></script>
<link href="js/files_upload/themes/explorer/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $("#input-8").fileinput({
        rtl: true,
        language: "he",
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"],
        maxFileCount: 10,
        maxFilePreviewSize: 5120, // 5 MB
        maxImageWidth: 150,
        maxImageHeight: 100,
        resizePreference: 'height',
        resizeImage: true,
        theme: "explorer",
        validateInitialCount: true,
    //  uploadUrl: "images/users_files",
        showRemove: true,
        showUpload: false,
        showZoom: false,
    //  required: true,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreviewAsData: true,
        layoutTemplates: {
            main1: "{preview}\n" +
            "<div class=\'input-group {class}\'>\n" +
            "   <div class=\'input-group-btn\'>\n" +
            "       {browse}\n" +
            "       {upload}\n" +
            "       {remove}\n" +
            "   </div>\n" +
            "   {caption}\n" +
            "</div>"
        }       
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why not remove ALL the JS and CSS includes from the modal, and include them into the primary site?  That should alleviate the need to include jQuery a second time while still allowing your upload scripts to function.

Comment: @RobertC - r u sure that i can do that? the modal file is not independent file that need to include all the script/css files?

Comment: All the Modal does is insert that content in via AJAX. So long as your jQuery is written with that in mind you can avoid redundancies like this.